# Как принудительно завершить события click в контроле Button?

Tags: c#

Как принудительно завершить события click в контроле Button?

Comment: Да. Вызывайте `return;`.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду, конкретно? Покажите пример того, чего Вы пытаетесь добиться

Comment: Как ни странно, уточнение «WPF или WinForms» тут не требуется.

Comment: Извините, WinForms . return помог